# Star Rating Primefaces always zero

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, rating

I have a problem with rating of Primefaces 3.2.
I use it on my JSF project, but it set ALWAYS zero rate.
Why ? How can i solve this ?
This is my code XHTML page:

```
<p:rating value="#{mybean.rating}">  
  <p:ajax event="rate" listener="#{mybean.onrate}" update="messages,spanResult"  /> 
</p:rating>
```

And this is my bean code:

```
@ManagedBean(name="mybean")
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable{
  public void onrate(RateEvent rateEvent){
    FacesMessage message1 = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Rate Event", "You rated:" + ((Double) rateEvent.getRating()).intValue());  
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message1);
    ....
   }

   private double rating; 

   public double getRating() {  
       return rating;  
   }  


   public void setRating(double rating) {
       this.rating = rating;  
   }  

   ...
}
```

Comment: Do you have the correct scope class in your import list (javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped) and not the CDI session scope?

Comment: Thanks but i solved. It was a very stupid problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved.
I need to insert the xhtml code inside `<h:form>`.